# Table view inside a normal view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm doing this iPhone project where I need to have a (dynamic) table view inside a normal view controller. I didn't choose a Table View Controller because I need to put other stuff in the page. Imagine a page with text fields, buttons and my small table view of about 4-5 cells.

When I run the app, I need to touch a button to segue to this view. The I click the button, the app crashes and tells me that:

> 2012-07-22 14:40:57.304 How Many?[3055:f803] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061

This is my .H file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProjectViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

This is my .M file:

```
#import "ProjectViewController.h"

@interface ProjectViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProjectViewController


//MyViewController.m
#pragma mark - Table View Data Source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    return cell;
}


@end
```

I control-dragged from the table view to my controller to set the delegate and the datasource.

What did I do wrong??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you plz show us the .h file? @interface ProjectViewController: UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>{}. Is it like this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. The complete code of my .H file is up there in my question. Am I suppose to put something else in it?

Comment: Did you have an outlet for the tableview?

Comment: @luyuan, that's not necessary as long as he's not reference it(e.g: Call -reloadData or so) in the code.

Comment: @RaymondWang  Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] seems to tell us that the prototype cell isn't there. Plz check the comments under my answer. The problem solved by set an outlet and wire it to the tableview in the storyboard:)

Comment: @luyuan, yes the cell is missing. I don't know why set up the outlet will do the magic but if you check my answer, I created a cell if it is nil. I just wanna point it out the truth that he should initialize the cell if there isn't any. As long as setting the outlet does work for him. Lol

Comment: As the cell is created in the storyboard. The outlet will get it. But if not set the outlet and wire it. He/she should alloc and init the cell as in your answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Try to make an outlet in your `.h` file and wire it to the `tableView` in your `storyboard`

**ProjectViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

**ProjectViewController.m**

```
@synthesize myTableView;

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Now, that's a dumb mistake on my part! I fortot to create an outlet for my table view. Well now it works perfectly fine :) Thanks to you.

For those having the same problem: add the following in your .H file:   


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Comment: I edited too much, so my answer reappeared under your comment! Anyway thanks for your help, good night!

Comment: Did you use ARC? If not you can have this : @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

Comment: @AnthonyGuay Maybe you are not using ARC

Comment: @AnthonyGuay if luyuan helped you, then please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to their answer so that they get the credit for it, and is your way of thanking them.  Welcome to SO (Stack Overflow)!

Answer (score 0):

In your -cellForRowAtIndexPath, if you do this, you will be fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
             reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

return cell;
```

}

The problem is your cell never got memory allocated and initialized. That's why you get the error.