# Can I have another tableview inside a table view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController`(tvc2) where instead of using a `ViewController` to show my details from another `TableViewController`(tvc1), I used tvc2. Basically, tvc2 is a grouped table that only shows detail. But then I need a another `tableView`(tv3) inside tvc2 that is a list. Each `tableViewCell` of the `tableView` should be segued to another detail `ViewController`.

My question is can I add the `tableView` inside the `TableViewController`? And if it's possible, how can I differentiate the `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellRowAtIndexPath` methods from the `TableView` to the `TableViewController`?

Comment: you mean putting a tableview inside a tableviewCell right?

Comment: no, TableView inside a TableViewController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603119/table-view-inside-a-normal-view-controller

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072401/can-you-add-a-uitableviewcontrollers-tableview-to-another-view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**YES**, YOU CAN.
When you create `UITableView`, you need to set `dataSource` and `delegate`. In your case `dataSource` and `delegate` for both tableViews is `tvc2`.
In dataSource and delegate methods you need to fork code for each tableView (for example, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == tableView1)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    if (tableView == tableView2)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    if (tableView == tableView3)
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple as in case of using UISearchDisplayController. You only need to check tableView in delegate/dataSource methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) return 1; // tvc1 is self
    if (tableView == tvc2.tableView) return 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do this. Example code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    if(row == 0){

            Grupo_DAO *grupo_bd = [[Grupo_DAO alloc] init];
            static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"PL";
            UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PeriodoLectivoView" bundle:nil];
            [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
            PeriodoLectivo *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
            computerGrupos = [grupo_bd ObtenerGrupos: identAsig];
            Grupo_DTO *grupoprueba = [[Grupo_DTO alloc] init];
            grupoprueba = [computerGrupos objectAtIndex:section];
            cell.Inicio = grupoprueba.inicio;
            cell.Fin = grupoprueba.fin;
            return cell;

    }else{
        ....
    }
```

I put in the row 0 of my UITableView another table. For the table iniside the UITableViewController you have to create a .m and .h files (in this example @"PeriodoLectivoView" -> ListaPeriodoLectivo.m). And in this files you have the methods umberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellRowAtIndexPath, etc.

Hope it helps.